# ubuntu, issues using & on the command line

Tags: ubuntu, bash, terminal, vnc

The issue Im having is when I use &. For example

```
vncviewer 192.168.1.106 &
```

This should run vncviewer in the background, allowing me to continue using terminal for other stuff. vncviewer on the other end (on a vista box) responds in my ubuntu terminal with

```
Password:
```

I cant type the password, as that process is in the background, so I

```
[ctrl + a] fg %1 [enter]
```

to it, which is supposed to give that process 'focus'. However, at that point, the keyboard is unresponsive, as in ctrl-c dosent work, no text appears when I type, enter, esc.. all dead. :( The only way out is to close the terminal.

Very minor issue, everything works really, just would like not to have multiple terminals open. (Ive tried screen, would use it if there were tabs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

skip the & in this case...

simply start the vncviewer without forking... then after typing in password, hit control-z to background the task  (it will suspend it)... and type "bg" to let it continue to run in the background.

Comment: muchas gracias!